powertoys preview show application running with admin privileges that user did not use how to know that process id
when i open or restart main machine power toys preview show that a application is running with admin privileges .I need to find the process id and file location of that process .or alternatively you could recommend a good virus scanner because I think my machine is having a virus
quick note:
'1PAzUW1XfuqMBbvQncgRD7TJgrpCCXdYkL' this on my clipboard I tried to find the I could not so help me
I tried a uninstaller and tried couple of virus scanner
